# SVG component in Angular library project gives 'Unknown word' error

Tags: angular, svg, npm, angular-library

I am creating a npm library package in Angular 8.1.3

If I add an SVG file as a component template **in the library project** then the build command `ng build <project-name>` gives `my-comp.component.svg:1:1: Unknown word` error.

However if I add an SVG file as a component template in the main app, then it builds successfully. Please help.

```
Angular CLI: 8.1.2
Node: 12.3.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.1.3
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.801.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.801.2
@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr   0.801.2
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.801.2
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.801.2
@angular-devkit/core               8.1.2
@angular-devkit/schematics         8.1.2
@angular/cli                       8.1.2
@ngtools/json-schema               1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack                   8.1.2
@schematics/angular                8.1.2
@schematics/update                 0.801.2
ng-packagr                         5.3.0
rxjs                               6.5.2
typescript                         3.4.5
webpack                            4.35.2
```

Comment: I am having the same issue, did you figure anything out @Rahul?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this using below steps:

1. Update Angular CLI to latest version using

   `npm install @angular/cli`
2. Update `ng-packagr` using

   `npm i ng-packagr@latest`
3. Import `BrowserModule` in the root module of library project

   `import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';`

   `...`

   `@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule
    ]`
4. Then build the project using `ng build my-project` command

Answer (score 1):

I submitted a bug, looks like it got PRed in, just have to wait till it gets released.
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/15187.

I inlined my svg, and I think it worked, you could try that in the meantime.